# Gem Bomb Only Amulet?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

Can someone provide some advice on how to win a field with Gem Bombs only?

- What field to use?
- What skill level and how are skill points distributed?
- What build strategy do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you have premium or not. If you have premium, winning a field with only gem bombs is very simple. All you have to do is this:

1. pick a field with very weak monsters (G13 is a good field for this)
2. select the option "giants only" and "endurance"
3. create a few fairly high-level gems (at least level 3 or 4, otherwise you might not kill the monsters)
4. start the first wave. when the first giant monsters appear, pause the game (freeze time)
5. take the high-level gems you made, and use them to kill all of the monsters from the first wave. then, create 3 grade-1 gems and bomb your orb with them. (causing you to end endurance)
6. you will not receive many experience points from doing this, but you will get the journey amulet, as you won the endurance using only gem bombs

Make sure that you destroy ALL of the monsters in the first wave, as if you do not it will not qualify the first wave as "beaten".

If you do not have premium, this is a bit more tricky, and requires a fairly high wizarding level, and use of the "wild gem" skill.

Again, pick a field with as few monsters as possible. (G13 was the one I did)

1. your skill balance should look like this. forge: maxed out (30), multiple damage mastery: maxed out (20), "wild gem": maxed out (20). the rest of your skill points should go into "focus"
2. sell the starting "wild gem" that you got from the skill
3. create a huge amount of grade 2 multiple damage gems (yellow) (I did this on field G13, and grade 2 worked for me)
4. start the waves
5. enter "gem bombing mode" by shift-clicking the gem bomb spell. this will let you bomb without having to drag the gems. (work out how gem-bombing mode works before using it though)
6. start throwing gem bombs, preferably at clusters of enemies
7. if you start feeling pressured, don't forget that you can freeze time and still use gem bombs. this helps out if there are a lot of monsters coming from different directions
8. when you run out of gems, create more grade 2 multiple damage. if you are worried about the monsters not dying in 1 hit, create grade 3 instead of grade 2
9. that's about it, with only 8 waves, you should be able to handle the monsters fairly easily. also, don't worry about a few monsters leaking, you can always get them on their second time through the maze

It is kind of a hard journey amulet, considering it only gives you 300 exp, but it does look pretty cool... and anyway its nice to say you have all the journey amulets.

Sources: experience playing the game.